# Prompt Solr Query using SolrJ

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying to structure a solr query using solrj. From my understanding of Solr-7.5.0 all libraries and dependencies for solrj should be included in my solr installation. Below is my /dist folder followed by my /dist/solrj-lib folder

### [image: dist]

[image: dist/solrj-lib]

Now, my query will be tied to an html post form but I want to get the solrj working first. Here is the entirety of my solrj

```
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
    import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.HttpSolrClient;

    String queryInput = q;
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(queryInput);
    SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder (
        "http://localhost:8983/solr/sqltest")
        .build();
    QueryResponse response = client.query(query);
    SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();
```

This will not compile because it does not recognize my classes (SolrClient, SolrQuery, etc). I am sure there are countless issues right now but Im not sure where to start.
As a side question, I was looking into other APIs that are not in compiled code. Would one of these be better used for a web application or is it safe to use solrs native solrj?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Are you using Maven?

Comment: @freedev I am currently not using Maven or an IDE.

Comment: And how do you handle all the dependencies?

Comment: @freedev manually? I am very new to java

Comment: I suppose, I strongly suggest to use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) with an IDE like [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) or [Intellj IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/). Maven will help you to resolve all the dependencies and the ide, well, it will help you to handle all the rest...

Comment: I did a [simple Solrj project](https://github.com/freedev/solr-import-export-json) built with Maven. Use this as skeleton of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely use SolrJ - in fact, if you're writing a Java application, it's the recommended way of interacting with Solr. See [Using SolrJ - Building and Running SolrJ Applications](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/using-solrj.html#UsingSolrJ-BuildingandRunningSolrJApplications) for further details than what I've given below.

I've assumed you're on Windows from your screenshots - if you're on Linux or OS X, replace `;` with `:` as the path separator below.

To include the SolrJ jar, you need to include a `-classpath ".;path-to-solr-solrj-7.5.0.jar` argument when running `javac`. This is the only jar required to compile your application.

When running it you'll have to include the jars found in the `solrj-lib` path. You can do this by including a class path argument to `java` with your files. Use `java -classpath ".;path-to-solrj-lib\*` to [include all the jar files in the directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)#Adding_all_JAR_files_in_a_directory).

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh I will definitely need to add to my classpath. Just for reassurance do the contents of my solrj-lib and dist files look complete for the classes i would need to add? I dont see a jar explicitly named solrclient or solrquery? Im planning creating a package of all classes i will be using and add those to the classpath

Comment: From what I can tell it looks correct. As long as you're using the directories you extracted from the solr distribution zip, everything should be there. The classes are located inside the jar.